# PhpStorm xdebug on WSL2 - Waiting for incoming connection

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am running Windows with WSL2 and Ubuntu 18.04 in there. The webserver is running in Docker Desktop. Xdebug is set up and PhpStorm configured. But I always get "Waiting for incoming connection with ide key 'PHPSTORM'". I have also installed Xdebug toolbar in the browser and set the ide key there.

In the run configuration I set the server to `sw6.dev.localhost`. That is the URL in the browser. But I also tried `127.0.0.1` and `localhost`. Always the same result. Do you have an idea what is going wrong?

I have read that the docker container always got a new IP. Could that be the problem?

In the docker file I have set: `xdebug.remote_host = host.docker.internal`

In the xdebug.log I got:

```
[27] I: Checking remote connect back address.
[27] I: Checking header 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'.
[27] I: Remote address found, connecting to 172.26.0.1:9000.
[27] W: Creating socket for '172.26.0.1:9000', poll success, but error: Operation in progress (29).
[27] E: Could not connect to client. :-(
```

My xdebug.ini looks like this:

```
    xdebug.remote_enable=1
    xdebug.remote_autostart=0
    xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
    xdebug.remote_port=9000
    xdebug.remote_log=/tmp/xdebug.log
    xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
    xdebug.profiler_enable=0
    xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
    xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/tmp/xdebug"
    xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%R.%t"
    xdebug.auto_trace=0
    xdebug.trace_enable_trigger=1
    xdebug.trace_output_dir="/var/www/html/traces"
    xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%R.%t"
    xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
```

I am not sure about the IP. Should that be the IP of the docker container with nginx?

I have set `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` in PhpStorm's vmoptions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) I would suggest to start here: https://learnxdebug.com/ 2) You can then google "Xdebug WSL2 PhpStorm" to see relevant articles.